# How do I create an 'IN' validation rule in MS Access 2013

Tags: database, validation, ms-access

I have a shorttext column on my table named 'Title'.
I want to validate the input so that only 'Mr', 'Mrs','Ms','Miss' and 'Dr' are allowed. I don't want to create a lookup table. I've attached a screenshot of what I'm trying  to achieve but I keep on getting an error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work. Check carefully quotations in the Validation Rule. They should be straight double quotes, do not try to copy from MS Word, it converts straight quotes to "pair" ones by default. Just re-type quotes in validation rule manually.

Comment: I've used [Title] In("Mr","Ms","Mrs","Miss","Dr") as well as  In("Mr","Ms","Mrs","Miss","Dr"). Both give me the above error

Comment: @Eminem Just tested on Access 2007 - that rule works fine. The only amendment it makes is adding a space after "In" and before the brackets begin, but that shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: Just tried copy-paste In("Mr","Ms","Mrs","Miss","Dr") to validation rule for text field in Access 2010 - it worked fine, space after IN was added automatically when changed focus from Validation Rule row

Comment: I found the problem. I have to separate it with a semi colon and not a comma. Will award you the points though

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
[Title]="Mr" Or [Title]="Ms" Or [Title]="Mrs" Or [Title]="Miss" Or [Title]="Dr"
```

**Solution:**

```
In("Mr";"Ms";"Mrs";"Miss";"Dr")
```